# If statement shortcode

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

So, I am creating a shortcode to return some ACF content.

The following code works:

```
function howitworks() {
    $page = get_page_by_title('shop');
    if (have_rows('steps', $page->ID)) :
        while (have_rows('steps', $page->ID)) : the_row();
            $image = get_sub_field('icon');
            $i = '<div class="col">
                    <img src="'.$image['sizes']['thumbnail'].'" alt="'.$image['alt'].'" title="'.$image['alt'].'" />
                    <h2>'.the_sub_field('step').'</h2>
                    <p>'.the_sub_field('description').'</p>
                </div>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    return $i;
}
add_shortcode('howitworks', 'howitworks');
```

The problem I am having is I'd like to add a div container in-between the `if` and the `while`. I have tried multiple ways. I tried another variable like `$j = '<div class="test">'` then added another return `return $i, $j`...but then I have a syntax error. If I add a semi-colon the error goes away, but the div doesn't get returned. If I wanted the div inside the while, I'd be fine. But it seems like I'm having issues because I'm trying to put it outside the while.

The other thing I tried was just to return the outer div like: `return '<div class="test">';` which will return the div, but then my original return doesn't return anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

function howitworks() {
    $page = get_page_by_title('shop');
    $html = '';
    if (have_rows('steps', $page->ID)) :
        $html .= '<div class="test">';
        while (have_rows('steps', $page->ID)) : the_row();
            $image = get_sub_field('icon');
            $html .= '<div class="col">
                    <img src="'.$image['sizes']['thumbnail'].'" alt="'.$image['alt'].'" title="'.$image['alt'].'" />
                    <h2>'.get_sub_field('step').'</h2>
                    <p>'.get_sub_field('description').'</p>
                </div>';
        endwhile;
        $html .= '</div>';
    endif;
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('howitworks', 'howitworks');
?>
```

EDIT: I change up my code for replace the_sub_field by get_sub_field

Comment: This almost worked to a "T", the `h2` and `p` tags return empty, but the content appears above the `<div class="test">` on the page - the image appears right where it should be.

Comment: You need change all your "the_sub_field()" by "get_sub_field()"

Comment: Sam - That definitely worked! Posted by full code below...thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I wanted to give Sam credit, he solved the issue, so his answer is the right one...I just made a little tweak to get it 100% working. I made `get_sub_field` variables instead of calling them inline, which helped them display properly (instead of above my div container) My final code looks like:

```
function howitworks() {
    $page = get_page_by_title('shop');
    $html = '';
    if (have_rows('steps', $page->ID)) :
        $html .= '<div class="test">';
        while (have_rows('steps', $page->ID)) : the_row();
            $image = get_sub_field('icon');
            $step = get_sub_field('step');
            $desc = get_sub_field('description');
            $html .= '<div class="col"><img src="'.$image['sizes']['thumbnail'].'" alt="'.$image['alt'].'" title="'.$image['alt'].'" /><h2>'.$step.'</h2><p>'.$desc.'</p></div>';
        endwhile;
        $html .= '</div>';
    endif;
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('howitworks', 'howitworks');
```

Thanks,
Josh